# Maya not running and giving this error

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, 64-bit, software-sources

I installed maya 2020 on ubuntu 20.04 lts about 2 months ago. I was able to get it to run then, but now I get the following error message when I try to run the program. If anyone knows what any of this means, and how I might be able to fix this I would greatly appreciate it as I need this software for my research.

```
/usr/autodesk/maya2020/bin$ maya
root : ERROR : code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
root : ERROR : code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
root : ERROR : code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
root : ERROR : code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
root : ERROR : code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
root : ERROR : code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/python27.zip/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Initialized VP2.0 renderer {
  Version : 2016.11.53.12. Feature Level 5.
  Adapter : GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2
  Vendor ID: 4318. Device ID : 
  Driver : 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.100.
  API : OpenGL V.4.6.
  Max texture size : 16384 * 16384.
  Max tex coords : 32
  Shader versions supported (Vertex: 5, Geometry: 5, Pixel 5).
  Shader compiler profile : (Best card profile)
  Active stereo support available : 0
  GPU Memory Limit : 8192 MB.
  CPU Memory Limit: 15144.8 MB.
/usr/autodesk/maya2020/bin/maya.bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/autodesk/maya2020/bin/../lib/libOGSDeviceOGL4-16.so: undefined symbol: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
```

Answer (score 1):

Check /usr/autodesk/maya2020/support/python/2.7.11/README_ubuntu_hashlib.txt

Basically you will need to do this:

```
cd /usr/autodesk/mayaxxxx/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
sudo mv _hashlib.so rhel_hashlib.so
sudo cp /usr/autodesk/mayaxxxx/support/python/2.7.11/ubuntu_hashlib.so _hashlib.so
```

I had to do the following though:
`sudo cp /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so _hashlib.so`